# integrating 3rd party jars into eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

There are some third party jars that my RCP needs.
I wanted to use the .exe that the product export wizard creates.

My 3rd party jars location not fixed and also frequently getting updated.So i can not create plug-in for dependent jars since we have to create plug-in for 3rd party jars each time when any jar get updated.

I have added below relative path in MANIFEST.MF

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
deliverables/DependencyJars/xercesImpl.jar,
deliverables/DependencyJars/xml-apis-1.3.03.jar,
deliverables/DependencyJars/XmlSchema-1.3.2.jar,
deliverables/DependencyJars/xmlsec-1.4.0.jar,
```

Any idea how I can specify the classpath for the exe so that exe could pick up above relative path?

Is there any way so that we can integrate the 3rd party jars from changing location?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the plug-in wrapping these jars just once, and then replace the jars inside it when they are updated.

Comment: In addition to creating a wrapping plugin, you can use the external: keyword in the Bundle-ClassPath to allow them to be picked up from the system (absolute path, but you can use a java system property).  It may or may not be a good idea, but it can be done :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the JARs are included in the binary builds. Open your `MANIFEST.MF` or `plugin.xml` and go to the **Build** tab. Make sure that the JARs are selected in the **Binary Build** section.